# Como resolver um problema do pygames dando tela preta sendo que o código não aparenta ter erro?

Tags: python, pygame

To criando um jogo no pygames de queda livre, lançamento horizontal e lançamento vertical, e com a resposta de equação iria aparecer uma esfera na tela realizando o movimento que foi encontrado depois da equação, com os valores numéricos fixos o jogo estava rodando tranquilamente do jeito que eu queria, mas quando eu introduzi um menu e a opção de o jogador escolher os valores numéricos(ângulo, Velocidade etc...) o programa simplesmente começou a ficar com a tela preta e não importa oque eu fizesse ele não funcionava normalmente o código é esse aqui

```py
import pygame
import sys
import math

# Cores
BRANCO = (255, 255, 255)
VERMELHO = (255, 0, 0)
AZUL = (0, 0, 255)

# Inicialização do Pygame
pygame.init()

# Tela do jogo
LARGURA = 800
ALTURA = 600
TELA = pygame.display.set_mode((LARGURA, ALTURA))
pygame.display.set_caption("Lançamento de Projéteis")

# Variáveis do Projétil
angulo = 45
velocidade_inicial = 50
gravidade = 9.81
tempo = 0
altura = 0
x = 0
y = 0

# Fontes
FONTE = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 30)
FONTE_MENU = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)

# Textos
texto_menu = FONTE_MENU.render("Escolha as variáveis", True, BRANCO)
texto_angulo = FONTE.render(f"Ângulo: {angulo} graus", True, BRANCO)
texto_velocidade_inicial = FONTE.render(f"Velocidade inicial: {velocidade_inicial} m/s", True, BRANCO)
texto_gravidade = FONTE.render(f"Gravidade: {gravidade} m/s²", True, BRANCO)
texto_tempo = FONTE.render(f"Tempo: {tempo} s", True, BRANCO)
texto_altura = FONTE.render(f"Altura: {altura} m", True, BRANCO)
texto_x = FONTE.render(f"X: {x} m", True, BRANCO)
texto_y = FONTE.render(f"Y: {y} m", True, BRANCO)

# Menu de seleção de variáveis
MENU_VARIAVEIS = [
    {"texto": "Ângulo", "valor": angulo},
    {"texto": "Velocidade Inicial", "valor": velocidade_inicial},
    {"texto": "Gravidade", "valor": gravidade},
]

# Índice da variável selecionada no menu de seleção de variáveis
VARIAVEL_SELECIONADA = 0


def altera_variavel():
    global angulo, velocidade_inicial, gravidade

    # Pergunta qual a variável a ser alterada
    print("Qual variável deseja alterar?")
    print("1 - Ângulo")
    print("2 - Velocidade Inicial")
    print("3 - Gravidade")
    opcao = int(input("Escolha a opção: "))

    # Solicita o novo valor da variável selecionada
    if opcao == 1:
        angulo = int(input("Novo ângulo: "))
    elif opcao == 2:
        velocidade_inicial = int(input("Nova velocidade inicial: "))
    elif opcao == 3:
        gravidade = float(input("Nova gravidade: "))
    else:
        print("Opção inválida")


while True:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score -2):

Tens de renderizar o texto em cada iteração do ciclo para o jogo atualizar em cada frame.

```
while True: 
    for evento in pygame.event.get(): 
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            TELA.fill((0, 0, 0))
            TELA.blit(texto_menu, (50, 50))
            TELA.blit(texto_angulo, (50, 150))
            TELA.blit(texto_velocidade_inicial, (50, 200))
            TELA.blit(texto_gravidade, (50, 250))
            TELA.blit(texto_tempo, (50, 300))
            TELA.blit(texto_altura, (50, 350))
            TELA.blit(texto_x, (50, 400))
            TELA.blit(texto_y, (50, 450))
            pygame.display.update()
```